# problem while accessing to partial views in express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

here's my views file: views/profile.ejs

```
<body>
    <% include partial/nav.ejs %>
    <!-- <%- include('partial/nav.ejs'); %> -->
    <h1>    Welcome to <%= person %> profile</h1>
    <p>
       <strong>The age: </strong><%= proObj.age%> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>Relationship Status: </strong><%= proObj.relation_status%> 
    </p>
    <div>
        <p>
            <strong>Hobbies: </strong>
                <% hobbies.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <li>  <%= item %> </li>
                    <% }); %>

        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this partial views file: views/partial/nav.ejs

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
```

when i reload the website i got this error popped into the server

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in C:\Users\Fo0ola\Desktop\SERVER-SIDE\views\profile.ejs while compiling ejs
```

Comment: It looks like the second `include` that you comment out is the correct statement.

Comment: No, i still got the same error popping

Comment: Did you remove the first code entirely... instead of commenting it? I had a one time experience where I got error for code that I've commented and after removing it only the code successfully run.

Comment: for no apparent reason it worked, i just removed the  entire code n rewrote it again with include i commented out  !

Comment: `<%- include('partial/nav.ejs'); %>` this is how you include partials in `ejs`